# GetWindowModuleFileNameW() get window's exe path fail with error 126?

Tags: winapi

## Goal

I am using `SetWinEventHook` with `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` to get title and exe name of foreground window.
The callback function I wrote are as follow:

```
void HandlerFunc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild,
    DWORD idEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime){
    wchar_t buff[256];
    wchar_t exe_buff[128];
    GetWindowTextW(hwnd,buff, 256);
    GetWindowModuleFileNameW(hwnd, exe_buff, 128);
    wcout << L"Window tile:" << buff << endl;
    wcout << L"process name:" << exe_buff << endl;
}
```

## Result

This code  success to get windows name , but often fail to get exe name. For msedge.exe , code will output.

```
Window tile:GetWindowModuleFileNameW() fail to window's get exe path? - Stack Overflow ...
process name:
```

I expect the code will print  `process name:$exe_path\msedge.exe`.

## My Try

1. I have try  others  windows. Most are same as msedge.exe, only print window's name.
2. I have try to print `GetLastError()` after `GetWindowModuleFileNameW()`.  it print 126 which means `Specified module could not be found` .

## Environment

Windows 10 , Compiler:MSVC

Comment: `GetWindowModuleFileNameW()` is not documented as reporting an error code on failure, so using `GetLastError()` for it is undefined behavior. On the other hand, `GetWindowTextW()` is documented as reporting an error code on failure.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But  when print process name successfully (success only for the console window of this code  itself), GetLastError() will print zero actually.

Comment: Undefined behavior is, well, undefined. Anything can happen, including what you expect. Also, your code lacks any error handling. You are ignoring the return values of both `GetWindowTextW()` and `GetWindowModuleFileNameW()`, they both tell you how many characters were written into your buffers. Don't output a buffer when there is nothing in it to show. And you should zero out your buffers before giving them to the APIs.

Comment: In any case, I found out why the code is not working for you. `GetWindowModuleFileNameW()` doesn't work as expected. See the duplicate question I linked to for an explanation. Now the "module not found" error makes more sense.